# Check if a number is Carmichael

Tags: algorithm, math, cryptography, primes, number-theory

I am trying to implement Modified Miller-Rabin Algorithm by Shyam Narayanan (https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2014/Narayanan.pdf). The algorithm demands to check if a number is Carmichael number.
Is there any possible algorithm to check if a number of the order 10^100 is a Carmichael number or not in reasonable time on a standard PC?(Other than by efficient factorization)

The Paper also conjectures that there is a `O(log(n)^4)` algorithm for checking whether a number is Carmichael or not. Do any such algorithms exist?

Comment: This might be better suited for [math.se] with the [reference-request] tag.

Comment: Cross-posted to Crypto.SE: [Check if a number is Carmichael](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34215/13022) and Math.SE: [Check if a number is Carmichael](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1726016)

Comment: Using Haskell perhaps? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Factorisation.html#g:7

Comment: see [Finding Carmichael numbers](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/carfind.pdf) by G. J. O. Jameson, [A Scheme for Generating Carmichael Numbers](http://www.d.umn.edu/math/Technical%20Reports/Technical%20Reports%202007-/TR%202011/TR_2011_9.pdf) by Trevor Brennan, and on Math Exchange the topic [Verifying Carmichael numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22461/verifying-carmichael-numbers). This should give you some idea of the math involved...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking about algorithms rather than code itself, i.e. it's not about programming.